# Flatten a list of nested dictionaries into a table

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, json-flattener

I have a list of dict like the one below

```
[
  {
    'profile': 
      '{"101":{"updatedBy":"user1","updatedOn":"2020-04-02","justification":"Tier 1 user"}}'
  },
  {
    'profile': 
      '{"102":{"updatedBy":"user2","updatedOn":"2019-06-08","justification":"Tier 1 user"}}'
  },
  {
    'profile': 
      '{"103":{"updatedBy":"user1","updatedOn":"2018-05-02","justification":"Tier 1 user"}}'
  },
  {
    'profile': 
      '{"104":{"updatedBy":"user2","updatedOn":"2020-06-12","justification":"Tier 1 user"}}'
  },
  {
    'profile': 
      '{"105":{"updatedBy":"user1","updatedOn":"2019-06-18","justification":"Tier 1 user"}}'
  }
]
```

I want to convert them into a data frame

[image]

Can anyone help me how to do it.

Comment: Are the values for the key `profile` all strings? Why are they in single quotes?

Comment: What is the source of this data? Why are the values always strings?

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami yes they are string

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the source of this data is DynamoDB

Comment: @LisaMathew You have to first convert all of that string to `dict` objects before you can do anything with it.